# ConnectyCube flutter sdk sample for chat is unstable for receiving message

Tags: android, ios, flutter, chat, connectycube

I try group chat with connectycube flutter chat sdk. I found connectycube chat server does not send chat message packet very often. It is also founded in connectycube chat flutter sample. I check this server bug with tcpdump utility. Is there a solution for this bug ?
PS : The lost messages is founded on chat dialogs admin page of ConnectyCube app adminstration page. (https://admin.connectycube.com/apps)